# How do I get a command to start from the top discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this blackjack command that I am very close to completing.

Everything works fine except for one little problem.

If the user decides they want to hit and not stand, their hand is updated, but they can no longer play.

Here's the command. Focus on the `if str(reaction.emoji) == hit:` because that's where my problem lies:

```
@client.command()
async def blackjack(ctx):
if ctx.author == client.user:
    return

global currentplayer
currentplayer = ctx.author
global playing
playing = True
global deck
deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14] * 4
global player_hand
player_hand = deal(deck)
global dealer_hand
dealer_hand = deal(deck)
global msg



msg = discord.Embed(title = f"<:blackjack:883416171834126366> {ctx.author.name}'s Blackjack game for $0", description = f"**{ctx.author.name}'s Hand:** {player_hand} \n Total: {total(player_hand)}\n \n **Dealer's Hand:** [{dealer_hand[0]}, ?]", color = 0xFFFF00)
msg.add_field(name = chr(173), value = "React with ✅ to **hit** or ❎ to **stand**.")
lobby = await ctx.send(embed=msg)



await lobby.add_reaction("✅")
await lobby.add_reaction("❎")


hit = '✅'
stand = '❎'


valid_reactions = ['✅', '❎']




def check(reaction, user):
  return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in valid_reactions
reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)



if str(reaction.emoji) == hit:
  

  if playing == True:

    
    draw(deck, player_hand)
        
    msg = discord.Embed(title = f"<:blackjack:883416171834126366> {ctx.author.name}'s Blackjack game for $0", description = f"**{ctx.author.name}'s Hand:** {player_hand} \n Total: {total(player_hand)}\n \n **Dealer's Hand:** [{dealer_hand[0]}, ?]", color = 0xFFFF00)
    msg.add_field(name = chr(173), value = "React with ✅ to **hit** or ❎ to **stand**.")
    lobby = await ctx.send(embed=msg)


    if total(player_hand) > 21:
        msg = discord.Embed(description = f"{ctx.author.name} busts! Dealer wins!")
        await ctx.send(embed = msg)
      
        playing = False
        endgame()
        return
  else:
    return

if str(reaction.emoji) == stand:


  if playing == True:

    

    while total(dealer_hand) < 17:

        draw(deck, dealer_hand)
        msg = discord.Embed(description = f"Dealer hits...")
        await ctx.send(embed = msg)
        if total(dealer_hand) > 21:
            msg = discord.Embed(title = f"<:blackjack:883416171834126366> {ctx.author.name}'s Blackjack game for $0", description = f"**{ctx.author.name}'s Hand:** {player_hand} \n Total: {total(player_hand)}\n \n **Dealer's Hand:** {dealer_hand}", color = 0xFFFF00)
            await ctx.send(embed=msg)

            msg = discord.Embed(description = f"Dealer busts! {ctx.author.name} wins!")
            await ctx.send(embed = msg)
            playing = False
            endgame()
            return

        
    msg = discord.Embed(title = f"<:blackjack:883416171834126366> {ctx.author.name}'s Blackjack game for $0", description = f"**{ctx.author.name}'s Hand:** {player_hand} \n Total: {total(player_hand)}\n \n **Dealer's Hand:** {dealer_hand} \n Total: {total(dealer_hand)}", color = 0xFFFF00)
    msg.add_field(name = chr(173), value = "Message 'hit' or 'stand' to play.")
    await ctx.send(embed=msg)
        
    if total(dealer_hand) > total(player_hand) and total(dealer_hand) <= 21:


           
        msg = discord.Embed(description = f"Dealer wins!")
        await ctx.send(embed = msg)
        playing = False
        endgame()
        return
    elif total(dealer_hand) == total(player_hand) and total(dealer_hand) <= 21:
            
        msg = discord.Embed(description = f"{ctx.author.name} and the Dealer tied.")
        await ctx.send(embed = msg)
        endgame()
        return
    else:
            
        msg = discord.Embed(description = f"{ctx.author.name} wins!")
        await ctx.send(embed = msg)
        playing = False
        endgame()
        return
  else:
    return
```

After reacting to the updated hands embed, nothing happens. I'm hoping that somebody out there can help solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: This is a lot of code, please consider adding a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```py
while playing:
    reaction = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
    if str(reaction.emoji) == hit:
        # your code here
        if check: # check if player hand is > 21
            # your code here
            playing = False
            endgame()
            break
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == stand:
        # your code here
```

This basically waits for reaction and executes your code. It does so until `playing` is `False` or `break` is called.